# VS2010: Add project reference in the properties sheet file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

Our solution contains ~50 projects. There is a special one among them which has to be build almost first because almost every other project calls its executable. I know that through the [Framework and References](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47w1hdab(v=vs.100).aspx) the build order can be defined by adding a reference to the project. Since I don't want to do it for every project and I want to ensure that every newly added project will reference the special one, my hope is that it is doable with the [Properties Sheets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/669zx6zc(v=vs.100).aspx#bkmkPropertySheets)

However, it seems that the Property Manager does not have option to modify the References for the .props files, at least I couldn't find it. Still, is there a way to do it?

Comment: It isn't managed by property sheet. Build dependencies are managed by either (a) references to said project (as you've noted) or (b) the Project dependencies pop-ups, which have a number of ways to reach; ex: you can right-click the project in the solution explorer and select "Project dependencies..." Your first choice is the best for libs as project references are eventually what drive automated manifest generation if you're using that feature for your projects. That you could easily do this for 49 projects in less time than the now-23 minutes this question has been open has its own irony.

Comment: You are right, modifying all these projects won't take that much time but my boss wants me to have it in the system for feature projects because some of the students, that use the system, don't know much about project configurations.

Comment: Tell your boss anyone that authors a project needs to reference what they use. The alternative is they need to add in a custom property sheet, the likes of which imho are far in-depth to setup. Don't get me wrong. I think the idea has merit, and maybe someone knows something I'm not aware of (maybe they added this feature in 2013 or 2015), but for 2010 I'm not aware of any other ways to do it than those mentioned.